# Modifying lists in a Python matrix algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I am working through some algorithm challenges to get some more Python practice. I am having some problems with a problem that requires changing values inside a python matrix (list of lists).

```
# Challenge
# After they became famous, the CodeBots all decided to move to a new building and live together. The building is represented by a 
# rectangular matrix of rooms. Each cell in the matrix contains an integer that represents the price of the room. Some rooms are 
# free (their cost is 0), but that's probably because they are haunted, so all the bots are afraid of them. That is why any room 
# that is free or is located anywhere below a free room in the same column is not considered suitable for the bots to live in.
# ex: matrix = [[0, 1, 1, 2],      [[x, 1, 1, 2],
#               [0, 5, 0, 0],  -->  [x, 5, x, x],  --> 5 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 9
 #              [2, 0, 3, 3]]       [x, x, x, x]]
```

My approach is two-fold: 1) first find all zeros in the matrix and replace that value with 'x'. 2) Once that happens, loop through all the lists and find the index of existing 'x', then use that index value and search for it in the other lists.. replace the numeric value with 'x' if that number is 'below' the existing 'x'.. hopefully that makes sense. I have the first part down and I have attempted the second piece a number of different ways but now am running into an error.. I feel like i'm very close. I also feel like my code is pretty inefficient (I am new to Python), so if there is some far more efficient way to do it please let me know.

I understand what the error means but I am having a hard time fixing it while getting the correct answer..The error is that the index is out of range.

My code:

```
def matrixElementsSum(matrix):
    numList = len(matrix) # essentially the number of 'rows' -> number of lists
    numCol = len(matrix[0]) # number of values in each list

    # replace 0's in each list with 'x'
    for x in matrix:
        if x.count(0) > 0:
            for index, i in enumerate(x):
                if i == 0:
                    x[index] = 'x'

    for x in matrix:
        for y in matrix[x]:
            if(matrix[x][y] == 'x'):
                x_ind = y
                for z in matrix:
                    if(z < x):
                        matrix[z][x_ind] = 'x'
     print(matrix)
```

Test scenario:

```
matrixElementsSum([[0, 1, 1, 2], 
                   [0, 5, 0, 0], 
                   [2, 0, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: You forgot to tell people what is the error message.

Comment: Sorry, the error message is index is out of range - I will edit the main post

Comment: What is the point of `if x.count(0) > 0:`? Anyway, you are trying toindex into your matrix with the *values in the matrix*: `for x in matrix: ... for y in matrix[x]`, `x` will be a `list`, a "row" in your "matrix"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still going to require nested for loops in some fashion or another since you are iterating over a list of lists, but you could simplify the logic a bit using list comprehensions.

```
def solver(matrix):
     mx = [[v if v else 'x' for v in row] for row in matrix]
     mxx = [[v1 if v2 else 'x' for v1, v2 in zip(row1, row2)] for row1, row2 in zip(mx[1:], matrix)]
     return mx[:1] + mxx
```

I first iterate over the matrix, and replace '0's with `"x"`s in the new matrix `mx`.

```
mx = [[v if v else 'x' for v in row] for row in matrix]
```

This is just a nested list comprehension, where we operate on each element per row, for every row per matrix. The `... if ... else ...` is just your classic ternary operator. If `v` holds (is not zero in our case), then it evaluates to the value before the "if", otherwise it evaluates to the value after the "else" - in this case `'x'`.

I then repeat the process, but offsetting the rows by one so that I can check if the above element is now an `"x"`.

```
mxx = [[v1 if v2 else 'x' for v1, v2 in zip(row1, row2)] for row1, row2 in zip(mx[1:], matrix)]
```

There's a bit to break down here. Lets start from the "outside" and work our way in.

```
... for row1, row2 in zip(mx[1:], matrix)
```

This zips the new matrix, offset by one (using `[1:]` slice notation), with the original matrix. So it returns an iterable functionally equivalent to the following list:

```
[(mx_row1, matrix_row0), (mx_row2, matrix_row1), (mx_row3, matrix_row2), ...]
```

This allows us to extract a given row *and* the row above it simultaneously, as `row1` and `row2`. Then the other half-

```
[v1 if v2 else 'x' for v1, v2 in zip(row1, row2)]
```

-repeats a similar process on each element per row, rather than row per matrix. We do not offset the elements in either row like we offset the rows of the `mx` matrix, but otherwise the logic is identical. We then again compare with our ternary operator to see if the above element is a `0`, and if so evaluate to `'x'`. We could easily have changed this to compare each element of each row of `mx` to `'x'` instead of `matrix` to `0`, but I decided to mirror the first list comprehension.

Once I have this new matrix `mxx`, I simply prepend the first row of `mx`, because we effectively skip that row when we offset our comparison. The result is a matrix with all `0`s and elements below replaced with `"x"`s.

---

As per clarification in the comments, if you wish you to mark an `"x"` if *any* of the above elements are `0`, not just the one directly above, you can accomplish this by taking a slice of that column of the matrix and using the `all()` builtin to see if any are `0`. Revised code below

```
def solver(matrix):
    return [[v if all(col) else 'x' for v, col in zip(row, zip(*matrix[:idx]))] for idx, row in enumerate(matrix, 1)]
```

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly! I have not used zip before, could you explain what that is doing here? I have only briefly used list comprehensions, i was not aware you could do a list comprehension inside a list comprehension. The 'outer' list comprehension for mxx is a bit confusing to me though. Also, does the v if v else 'x' automatically check for > 0 integers? how does it know what to replace with 'x'?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my post to break it down line by line

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the explanation. I will have to mess around with the code so I can get a better understanding visually

Comment: how could this be modified to include a scenario where all values in a 'column' change to 'x' if there is a zero 'above'? For instance the following example: [[1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 5, 0, 1], [2, 1, 3, 10]]. Your solution above changes the 3rd index in the second list to 'x', but then leaves the 3rd index in list 3 as 10.

Comment: I think somehow you have to loop through the possible offsets? mx[2:] in the zip method will compare the 3rd index to the 1st. If we assume there is a max number of lists = 5, can we somehow perform that loop?

Comment: @cexcelc I updated the answer with a paragraph at the bottom + modified code to handle that case. I originally misunderstood your question as marking `"X"`s for elements *directly* below `0`s.

Comment: wow, thanks again. I will have to look into your use of the '*' character and the all() method to get a better understanding of what they do

Comment: @cexcelc The `*` unpacks an iterable and passes each element as an argument individually. So I pass each row as an argument to zip, effectively transposing the matrix. And `all()` just asserts if none of the elements are falsey. its complement,`any()`, asserts if at least one is not falsey.